# How to spring-boot 2.4.0 and kotlin 1.4.20

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin

I am trying to build a spring-boot Microservice.
The build is  using releasee 2.4.0 of spring-boot.
I am trying to compile this build with the new release 1.4.20 of kotlin.

How can I build this without failures?
Try to create a kotlin Microservice with [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io). Edit the pom to use the newest kotlin release...

When building:

```
Execution compile of goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.4.20:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.4.20:compile: kotlin/reflect/KDeclarationContainer
...
```

If you choose kotlin as main language (as one should) and picks java 15, one get the following error:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unknown JVM target version: 15
[ERROR] Supported versions: 1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

There is something fundamentally wrong with the spring-boot configuration provided from [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io) as the target of the new kotlin version 1.4.20 is java 15: [what's new in kotlin 1.4.20](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew1420.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seemed to be a bug only visible on Mac OS Big Sur (intel version), but was solved by updating to kotlin release 1.4.21

Answer (score 0):

updating kotlin version works for me.

Comment: You better write the version you are using.

Comment: 203-1.4.31-release-IJ7148.5